# Hide maximize and mimize button winUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

I want to hide the maximize and minimize button, it's worked when set IsMaximizable and IsMinimizable to false, but when I want to custom title bar by adding:             `this.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;` , those buttons cannot be hidden anymore.

Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [WinUI Ex](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx) NuGet package from dotMorten. You can easily hide those buttons with these lines.

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using WinUIEx;

namespace WinUIExTest;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        WindowManager.Get(this).IsMinimizable = false;
        WindowManager.Get(this).IsMaximizable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using WinUIEx and also use that way, but it only works when not using this.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see the details. I posted an [issue](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/issues/78) at the WinUI Ex repo.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that this is issue on winUI3: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7628